# How to Display IFconfig information with perl program in Linux

Tags: perl, module, perl-module, cpan, ifconfig

I have an assignment where i am supposed to create a perl script in linux that will give an output similar to that of the linux command "ifconfig". I have started writing the script but I repeatedly get errors. I would like some assistance in correcting my code so it becomes fully operational. What the program needs to do specificaly is require a perimeter. for example when i run the script it will ask for an interface name, if I typed in "eth0" which will be the interface name, and then it should output as if i typed in the command “ifconfig eth0”. The assignment requires that I use these two packages Net::Int::Stats and Net::Ifconfig::Wrapper.
The code i have so far is below. I would really appreciate any help

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Int::Stats;
use Net::Ifconfig::Wrapper;

my $int            = 'eth0';
my $stat           = 'rx_packets';
my $Iface          = $ARGV[0];
my $get_Iface_data = Net::Int::Stats->new();
my $Iface_Info     = Net::Ifconfig::Wrapper::Ifconfig('list', '', '', '');

my $rx_packets  = $get_Iface_data->value($Iface, 'rx_packets');
while( my ( $Addr, $Mask ) = each %{ $Info->{$int}{'inet'} } ) { 
    print "\tinet $Mask $Addr"; 
}
```

Comment: user218001, are you passing in eth 0, "eth 0", or eth0? Probably, only eth0 is the proper one.

Comment: Can you please provide specific errors you get that you can't figure out?

Comment: Also, I'm betting you're going to want a newline on that print statement : `print "\tinet $Mask $Addr\n";`

Comment: I am trying to pass eth0, sorry for the confusion there. Errors i encounter = Global symbol "$get_Iface_data" requires explicit package name at ./ass3.pl line 8.
Global symbol "$Info" requires explicit package name at ./ass3.pl line 10.
Global symbol "$int" requires explicit package name at ./ass3.pl line 10.
Execution of ./ass3.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: That's correct - you don't assign anything to "$get_Iface_data" or "$Info" variables, and try to use them. (the actual error is because they aren't declared, but that's just a syntactic symptom of the bigger logical problem - you'd declare them when assigning via "my" if you assigned them). `$get_Iface_data` should probably be an object of Ifconfig class?

Comment: can you please put your suggestion in code format, so I may know how to implement it. thanks

Comment: Why do you hardcode `eth0`? Aren't you supposed to be passing that in to `$Iface`?

Comment: thts what im saying...im not sure how to do that, can you please explain how i would pass it to $iface.

Comment: But you do. `$ARGV[0]` is the first argument passed to your script.

Comment: OK..well is the rest of the code fine, it still doesn't work, in your opinion what else needs to be fixed

Comment: You don't do anything with $rx_packets. I haven't read the perldoc for either module, so I can't say exactly how you should be getting the info the mimic `ifconfig`. But, just by looking at this, I'm not sure that it will.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the whole script provided in the perldoc? That looks like what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Int::Stats;
use Net::Ifconfig::Wrapper;

my $Iface   = $ARGV[0];
my $get_Iface_data = Net::Int::Stats->new();
my $rx_packets  = $get_Iface_data->value($Iface, 'rx_packets');
my $Iface_Info = Net::Ifconfig::Wrapper::Ifconfig('list', '', '', '');
while( my ( $Addr, $Mask ) = each %{ $Iface_Info->{$Iface}{'inet'} } ) {
    print "\tinet $Mask $Addr\n";
}
```